# Why people don't notice the normal blind spot "punctum caecum" in each eye?

Tags: eye, field-of-vision-fov-test

I noticed a blind spot in my eye. I made field of vision test and doctor says: "All humans see like you, This is the normal vision".

Why did I notice this "blind area" and many other people don't even have an idea about it?

I thought of the following reasons but I don't know the truth:

1. The blind spot is very small.
2. It is far from the center of the eye (where things go blurry) and people focus on the center only.
3. Our brain is an excellent processor and can hide it.
4. We get used to see it since we were so young.
5. People rarely close one eye. They see using the two eyes so they see a complete picture.

Comment: For the people like me that didn't exactly know what was meant by "blind spot", the medical term is *punctum caecum*, which, interestingly enough, translates as blind *(caecum)* spot *(punctum)*... I should had realised what was meant.

Comment: Add 6. All of the above, and I think you have it.

Comment: You might get better answers on CogSci.SE or Biology.SE. I mostly agree with @BillOertell but I would omit #5 and maybe even #1, and emphasize #3 mostly: it actually isn't all that small, compared to visual acuity, and you don't start noticing it when you close one eye unless you carefully place something in the spot.